# Ver solo las ultimas 7 filas de un registro que coincida con un user_id

Tags: laravel

Estoy haciendo una web en laravel con la que quiero mostrar los últimos 7 registros de una base de datos que coinciden con un user_id (Osea que siempre se muestran 7 registros).

Por lo que no puedo utilizar simplemente los id de los registros porque esta columna la comparten todos los registros sin importar el user_id.

Quizás la solución mas eficiente no sea con Laravel o PHP sino con JavaScript, por favor diganme cual les parece mejor, gracias!

[image: Base de datos]

**Controller**

```
    function index(){
    $tareas = Tarea::all()->where("user_id", "=", Auth::id());
    $fechas = fecha::all()->where("user_id", "=", Auth::id());

    $authCheck = Auth::check() ;
    
    if($authCheck){
        if($tareas->count()>0){
            return view('noCero', compact('tareas', 'fechas'));
        }else{
            return view('cero');
        }
    }else{
        return view('auth.register');
    }
}
```

**View**(Solo pongo la parte donde se iteran los registros)

```
 @foreach($fechas as $fecha)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{$fecha->fecha}}</td>
                        @foreach($fecha->datosFecha as $dato) //datosFecha es el método de las relaciones entre tablas eloquent
                            <td>{{$dato->confirm}}</td>
                        @endforeach
                </tr>
            @endforeach
```

Comment: Me extrañaría mucho que no hubiera en Lara el una forma de  seleçcionar los últimos 7 registros. En tu caso cojes todos los que tengan el id indicado. No hay luego alguna manera de decir Limit =7, por ej? Por mi parte creo que sería más efectivo desde el PHP (para no enviar información que luego no necesitas)

Comment: Hola, se que en PHP se hace con el valor Limit pero en Laravel busque y no encontre nada parecido

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomiendo usar el método `paginate(7)`. De esta manera esta manera estarás mostrando solo los 7 primeros pero además en caso de que en algún momento decidas dar soporte a mostrar más, tendrás ya hecho todo el sistema de paginación. La línea te quedaría así:

```
$tareas = Tarea::where("user_id", "=", Auth::id())->paginate(7);
```

El objeto que te devuelve lleva más cosas además de los 7 elementos, pero puedes simplemente ignorarlos mientras no quieras usarlos.

Edit:
Usando el método `all()` obtienes una colección de elementos, y el método `paginate()` debe ser aplicado al objeto Query de eloquent, quitando el `all()` funcionará sin problemas.

Comment: Hola, ya lo había probado pero me devuelve un error: Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::paginate does not exist.

Comment: Qué versión de laravel estás usando?

Comment: Laravel 7: Laravel Framework 7.22.4

Comment: Estás seguro de que probaste a usar paginate sin el `->all()` primero? Porque si usas `all()` obtienes una colección y el `where` que usas no es el mismo que el del query builder, y el método paginate se debe aplicar sobre el query builder y no sobre la colección que obtienes con el otro método

Comment: No había visto que había que quitar el all(), acabo de probarlo y funcionó, muchas gracias.

Comment: Efectivamente, como te decía, el método `all()`devuelve una colección, y necesitas aplicar el `paginate()` al query :) Me alegro que te haya servido!